# How to find average CPU utilization over a period of time on datadog

Tags: monitoring, datadog

In our infra CPU utilization is being monitored by datadog SAS. The dashboard shows  CPU utilization over a period time graphically. How do I find the average CPU utilization over that period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Query Value widget. It can only show a single value, which is the average for the current time window that has been chosen.